# What does the Bind 9 query error log debug 2 qrysent, retry, restart numbers mean?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I am trying to trouble shoot some DNS problems with BIND 9 when I have a cache miss on my recursive resolver.

I've enabled debug 2 logging for query errors and am getting the following:

```
01-Jun-2015 03:04:41.539 debug 1: client 71.41.189.242#53761 (www.theonion.com): query failed (SERVFAIL) for www.theonion.com/IN/A at query.c:7005

01-Jun-2015 03:04:41.539 debug 2: fetch completed at resolver.c:3194 for www.theonion.com/A in 10.000137: timed out/success [domain:theonion.com,referral:1,restart:3,qrysent:11,timeout:10,lame:0,neterr:0,badresp:0,adberr:0,findfail:0,valfail:0]
```

Does anyone know exactly what this means.  The first entry looks like it Failed.

The second is a timed out/success (which one is it -- time our or success --  or is it a success that happened after a timeout value)

What are the numbers in the debug 2 line.  What is a referral, restart, querysent, etc.  Did this try the same query 11 times, 10 timed out and 1 responded?  What are there referrals and restarts?

Any Bind experts that can help me understand what is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BIND ARM is your friend whenever you're doing anything of complexity with BIND. In particular, this is documented in the section on [logging](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#id2575029). The interpretation should be that BIND followed 1 referral, tried 3 times to reach all known nameservers, sent 11 queries in the process, and timed out on 10 out of 11 queries.

> referral
>
> The number of referrals the resolver received throughout the
>   resolution process. In the above example this is 2, which are most
>   likely com and example.com.
>
> restart
>
> The number of cycles that the resolver tried remote servers at the
>   domain zone. In each cycle the resolver sends one query (possibly
>   resending it, depending on the response) to each known name server of
>   the domain zone.
>
> qrysent
>
> The number of queries the resolver sent at the domain zone.
>
> timeout
>
> The number of timeouts since the resolver received the last response.
>
> lame
>
> The number of lame servers the resolver detected at the domain zone. A
>   server is detected to be lame either by an invalid response or as a
>   result of lookup in BIND9's address database (ADB), where lame servers
>   are cached.
>
> neterr
>
> The number of erroneous results that the resolver encountered in
>   sending queries at the domain zone. One common case is the remote
>   server is unreachable and the resolver receives an ICMP unreachable
>   error message.
>
> badresp
>
> The number of unexpected responses (other than lame) to queries sent
>   by the resolver at the domain zone.
>
> adberr
>
> Failures in finding remote server addresses of the domain zone in the
>   ADB. One common case of this is that the remote server's name does not
>   have any address records.
>
> findfail
>
> Failures of resolving remote server addresses. This is a total number
>   of failures throughout the resolution process.
>
> valfail
>
> Failures of DNSSEC validation. Validation failures are counted
>   throughout the resolution process (not limited to the domain zone),
>   but should only happen in domain.